# Azure Pipelines dotnet restore error: $(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyFileVersion)' is not a valid version string

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, .net-core, azure-devops

I am running a .NET Core restore task (version 2.*).

It gives the error C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : '$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyFileVersion)' is not a valid version string. (Parameter 'value').

This is a net standard project and I am using automatic versioning.

csproj:
[image]

Auto-generated assemblyinfo.cs:
[image]

Comment: Did you clean your solution in the task and then restore?

Comment: There is a task to clean the solution?

Comment: Yea, there should be an option to clean and rebuild.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Could the project be restored successfully on local machine?